Cannot create transaction in spring-data-redis (No ongoing transaction. Did you forget to call multi?)
I have redisTemplate that is initialized with connectionFactory and has enabled transaction support. The problem is that redisTemplate.multi(); doesn't seem to create transaction.
 redisTemplate.multi();
 redisTemplate.opsForValue().multiGet(Arrays.asList( "test"));
 redisTemplate.exec(); 

No matter what I put between multi and exec, exec always returns error org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No ongoing transaction. Did you forget to call multi?
Connection to Redis works, queries that don't involve transactions work. When I use discard() right after multi() it says org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Unknown redis exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection has no active transaction
Any ideas what could be the problem or how could I debug this?

Instead of calling multi(), exec(), and other operations directly on the RedisTemplate, it's often better to use the execute() method with a SessionCallback. This ensures that all operations are performed on the same connection.
public void performTransaction() {
        try {
            redisTemplate.execute(new SessionCallback<List<Object>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Object> execute(RedisOperations operations) throws DataAccessException {
                    operations.multi();
                    operations.opsForValue().multiGet(Arrays.asList("test"));
                    // Add more operations here
                    return operations.exec();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

